# macports: list out my own ports

Tags: macports

Over time, I have customized quite a number of ports and place them in my /Users/calvin/ports directory tree.

Is there a convenience command to list out all these personalized ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried `ls /Users/calvin/ports/`?

Comment: This is okay when I had a small number of custom install ports. But as the number increases and they are all nested in their categories, it gets increasingly difficult to keep track with a simple 'ls'

Answer (score 2):

Yep:

```
port installed
```

From the help:

```
port help installed
Usage: installed

List installed versions of the given port, or all installed ports if no port is given
```

Comment: Hey Steve, I am aware of this command but this lists out all my installed ports instead of just my 'custom' installed ports (ports with a Portfile that I specifically wrote). What I want is to be able to list out all my custom installed ports.